# A lemma about the pure states

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

There is a quotation of a book:

> **Lemma 3.4.5.** Assume that both $A$ and $B$ are unital and abelian C*-algebras. Then for every C*-norm $\|\cdot\|_{\alpha}$ on $A\odot B$ and pair of pure states $\phi\in S(A)$, $\psi\in S(B)$ the linear functional $\phi \odot\psi: A\odot B\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ extends to a state on $A\otimes_{\alpha} B$. (Here, $S(A)$ denote the state space of $A$).
>
> **Proof.** Let $P(A)$ (resp. $P(B)$) denote the pure states on $A$ (resp. $B$). Let 
>   $$U=\{(\phi, \psi)\in P(A) \times P(B): |\phi\odot \psi(x)|\leq\|x\|_{\alpha} ~, \forall x\in A\odot B
> \}.$$
>   Then the lemma asserts that $U=P(A)\times P(B)$.
>
> So, ....

**I do not know why "the lemma asserts that $U=P(A)\times P(B)$."** Does this equation imply the conclusion hold?

Comment: I changed ||.|| to \|\cdot\|.  Instead of $||.||$, you see $\|\cdot\|$.  Remember that $\TeX$ was deliberatly designed for this sort of thing (and MathJax is based on a fragment of $\TeX$). ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: It’s astonishing how *different* C*-norms may exist on $A\odot B$ for unital and abelian C*-algebras. Doesn’t Gelfand representation constrain possible norms to *the only* possible one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not saying that the conclusion holds. They are phrasing it in a way that allows them to prove it.  If there were $\varphi$, $\psi$ such that $\varphi\odot\psi$ does not extend to a state, then you would have $\mathcal U\subsetneq P(A)\times P(B)$.

Comment: So if we prove $U=P(A)\times P(B)$, then all the linear functional $\phi \odot \psi: A\odot B \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ can extend to a state on $A\otimes_{\alpha} B$, right?

Comment: Yes indeed. $ \ $

Comment: Oh, thanks Martin

Comment: In the Lemma, $\phi \odot \psi: A\odot B \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ can extend to a state on $A \otimes_{\alpha} B$. Is this state on $A\otimes_{\alpha} B$ a pure state?